# Problem rendering MathJax with Weebly

Tags: latex, weebly

Like many mathematics grad students, I have a professional website, which I built using Weebly because of its relative ease of use. In order to display mathematics nicely, I've been using MathJax which has worked extremely well until a few days ago, when it stopped rendering on the published website. The odd part of this is that it renders just fine in the auto-preview window of Weebly's HTML/CSS editor. I contacted Weebly's support team and the person with whom I spoke was unable to provide me with any satisfactory answers and I'm at something of a loss as to what to do from here, short of rewriting my entire website from scratch and hosting it on my department's server instead, which is obviously not something I really want to do.

The "tried and true" method of using MathJax with Weebly, which worked fine until recently, is to insert the code:

```
<script 
   src="http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML">
</script>
```

before the

```
</head>
```

tag in the landing.html file.

Attached are images displaying the perplexing difference between the auto-preview and the published website.[image: HTML/CSS editor] [image]